# How to rendering popup using functions in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

How to create a composite UseModal into which you can pass a component
in my example there is no access to the context
to the router and others
How to create this composable correctly

My example

```
<script setup lang="ts"> 
import { useModal } from '@/composables/useModal'; 
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';

const modal = useModal(); modal({ content: MyComponent, }); 

</script>

//useModal

import { h, render, ref, type Ref, type Component } from 'vue'; 
import AppModal from '@/components/App/Modal/AppModal.vue';

interface ModalOptions { content: string | Component; positionBody?: 'center' | 'bottom', isCloseButton?: boolean, }

const modalInstance: Ref<null | HTMLElement> = ref(null);

const useModal = () => {

const closeModal = () => { if (modalInstance.value) { render(null, modalInstance.value); document.body.removeChild(modalInstance.value); modalInstance.value = null; } };

const modal = (options: ModalOptions) => { closeModal();
const container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

const modalSlots = {
  content: typeof options.content === 'string'
    ? () => options.content
    : () => h(options.content as Component, null, {}),
};

const modalContent = h(AppModal, {
  show: true,
  positionBody: options.positionBody,
  isCloseButton: options.isCloseButton,
  onClose: closeModal,
}, modalSlots);

render(modalContent, container);
modalInstance.value = container;
};

return { modal, closeModal }; 
};

export default useModal;
```

Comment: Use portals/teleports.

Comment: Good option but needs to be created composable useModal

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I need to create a composable UseModal in which there will be a function to open a modal window into which I can pass any component

Comment: in my example, the AppModal is not visible in VDom and in components that do not have access to the slots, for example, to the router
Could you help me?

Comment: You can use a teleport in root component and interact with it from a composable via global service (can be global store or just some singleton), or use a teleport in the same comp as a composable, so it can be provided with a ref. This is how most vue modals work.